# How to re-index CtrlP Vim plugin?

Tags: vim, macvim, ctrlp

I've been using CtrlP for a while now, but I still haven't figured out how to re-index it. So whenever I want to create a new file I have to close all existing vim sessions, create the file, and then re-open them back. Otherwise the new file won't show up in the results.

I've been doing this without thinking much although this is really a huge pain in the ass. Today I decided to finally ask. Anyone know how to re-index CtrlP? I couldn't find it in the doc.

Comment: CtrlP is the name of a plugin, not a shortcut. Well, it's also the default shortcut, but Vlad is talking about the plugin.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Did you read CtrlP's documentation? The answer is there, of course:

<kbd>F5</kbd>

Seriously, `:help pluginname` should be the first command to issue after installing a plugin. After `:helptags ~/.vim/doc`, maybe.

Comment: I'm sorry about this, I have to admit that I totally missed it. By the way F5 doesn't work on my macbook, as it changes screen brightness. I've tried fn-F5 but that doesn't work either...

Comment: I don't own a MacBook. The command is `:CtrlPClearCache`: if `<F5>` doesn't work for you try to map it to something that works.

Comment: I do have a MacBook, and `<F5>` works for me.  You need to have CtrlP open first though.  So, do `:CtrlP`, then push `<F5>`.  On the mac, that'll likely need to be `Fn-<F5>`, unless you've told Mac OS X to treat the function keys as standard function keys (System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard -> Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys).